# Sum of products with K elements with different indexes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a fast way to find a $SUM(N,K)$ where we define $SUM(N,K)$ to be 
$$SUM(N,K)=\sum a_{i1}a_{i2} \cdots a_{ik},$$ where $a_{ij}$ are $K$ numbers chosen from $N$ numbers.

For example $SUM(3,2)=a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+a_{1}a_{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sums are called
[Elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
and can be calculated relatively fast by means of
[Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)
via sums of powers of $a_k$, starting with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$.